# Streaming google photos videos in iOS not working (nor in Safari)

Tags: ios, google-photos, google-photos-api

I am trying to use the base url provided by google photos API (example below) but it is not streaming not in iOS not in Safari.
I am using AVPlayer in iOS and receive the following error:

Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11850 "Operation Stopped" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x13fb86740 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12939 "(null)"}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=The server is not correctly configured., NSLocalizedDescription=Operation Stopped}

As I understand from other posts, this is a server side issue, but then I would need an workaround (or google fixing it for me).

Is there anyone with a solution?

Here an example of the url:

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/lr/AJ-EwvnThhlej4l_8c6rnsRsPcFlhX1vlMSjCe8yt9o8LLvDCbINXdA_9K-ufP6ye7m0xDd284VuNhOTosGF1v1RsDbInVpfee9_bfKqk1Q-1FqF7DjPJODeQ-LTZ91yuHlB3MQjf6onkPvL-3B2AzWo4Ftr_9YCX4G657DLuxD6K-bDd3zOt92Kt22yetoxfz_lbHr4pe5M6ztzS4ncG8ewc8XwZndmjgQHcJKJqG8jdxMXqeA1C5pblqbqUiSbYF25XwNrPlEpiaYnaFbbQEJySX4KRN7YqzIbf_bpuwYFt2MTbOZJeCjOppMxj5baHc4gbx77Lw5BKg2subHNtrWEg5YuTrnSuukLZkQyo59IK6tg_UzU0AHB7PepIAeaQo_gw_EnuLfewZGTp0hGHWy8iODd6gu9LwUgjVhusYfeTwCZ79jXp9zTXxUnXbcDYd410CapSyl0mAgF2jKU7Gorc44jTcBr_8LdNUD8cOLBfJQ3BayzkrauXCzUrMDIVi_bGfINK9C8-rsmNHbuG4GqfLXeXsLElPVA13gPIehs-r_jv4a2VKbV6o7RUuhTIAncKnQaK0vvyp1tQ9YQBpotC2xaG8-uEflvKv3jF2_52nvjrFpIDvp0pDYsLOHzLUiidTwq7nWs4cBatH7G2d3QYHZZ_9p7CflHKwTrJWHflF7arcaeVIaWmwD4qMQFjCn6eX7lODmGJIXJhLqILwv8VfmntRfbxgS-SycYS6WfyN3M5kxmzOzQ5WPr1nKzn8PTfC-6Lqqu0mi6uPkCAXFQeAOx104UBnCnCshJs_QeWbsROvYIe8Xn1-CNf4DgSRqTTN5bAa_5f9aP5USRM2E58wpG7JemB-ET2emHNuM1qHCysA28M3QLb-ao4_LPlaPdkIWL-5ww=dv

Comment: Same issue here, any progress? did you reach out to Google about this?

Comment: .. I didn't see any bug on google side about this so i filed one here, and referenced this post: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/156198845

Comment: @xaphod:  Any update on this?

Comment: Did you see the link in my previous comment and Google’s response? No update beyond that.